# Rounding to two decimal places

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to round a variable to two decimal places. I already know of one way to do it. For example

```
float a = 12345.343f;
System.out.printf("2f\n%" , a);
```

However, I am having trouble with rounding after the print statement. For example this is what i'm trying to do.

```
float money;
System.out.print("Enter how much money you have: ");
money = keyboard.nextFloat();
```

What I would like the output to show is the print statement asks you to enter your money, say 12345.6789, then it rounds to 12345.68, The final statement being

```
Enter how much money you have: 12345.68
```

The issue I'm having is I can't do this without first initializing money, but if I do that, the print statement will print the value I initialized it to, not what the user entered. Keep in mind I'm a beginner programmer. If you can, please explain it in a way a person who is just beginning would understand.

Comment: If precision is a concern you should use `double` (or even BigDecimal) rather than `float`.  `float` as up to 7 digitis of precison which means it might not represent a number like `12345.68` accurately. However `double` has up to 16 digitis of precision.

Comment: Most decimal fractions are not exactly representable as binary fractions, which are the basis of Java's `float` and `double` data types.  Therefore, financial data storage and computation often rely on *fixed-point* representations, such as an integral number of cents (or whatever the smallest possible currency denomination may be).  `BigDecimal` is a little more complicated to use, but it, too, can serve this purpose well.

Comment: You cant edit the already printed or typed text on the console like that afaik without a different console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float roundedValue = Math.round(a * 100.0)/100.0;
```

Rounds to 2 decimal places.

Comment: This may be the answer the OP is after, but do be aware that in most cases the mathematical result of the division will not be exactly representable as a `float`.  This may or may not be ok.

Comment: OP wants to ask, have input, then change what was typed in input and replace it on screen. This just rounds it.